# How Can I Repeat a Table Header if it Occupies Another Page

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, booktabs, xltabular

I created this table:

```
\usepackage{tabularx, longtable, booktabs, xltabular, enumitem}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet, nosep, leftmargin=*,
                     before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
             after ={\end{minipage}}}

\newlist{tabenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumerate]{label*=\arabic*.,
                       leftmargin=*,
               nosep,
               before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
               after=\end{minipage}}
```

```
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{p{0.5\linewidth} X}
\label{tab:choix-de-carriere-different}\\
\caption{Choix de carrière: ingénieur logiciel}\\
\toprule
Information & Recherche \\
\midrule
Description de la carrière &
Les ingénieurs logiciels se concentrent sur l'application des principes d'ingénierie aux programmes. Chaque ingénieur logiciel écrit et valide le code des programmes d'une entreprise. Tout comme les avocats, les ingénieurs en logiciel se spécialisent dans différents domaines. Il y a le développement Web, le traitement de texte, le développement de jeux.\\
\addlinespace
Habiletés et compétences nécessaires pour cet emploi &
\begin{tabitemize} 
\item savoir le codage 
\item bien à créer la documentation 
\item savoir des langages de programmation 
\item savoir des compilateurs 
\item savoir des licences de logiciels 
\item bien au débogage  
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Le salaire annuel & 83 345 \$\\ 
\addlinespace
Nomme trois différents endroits pour travailler en faisant cette carrière. Par exemple, une infirmière peut travailler dans un hôpital, une clinique privée ou dans des maisons de retraites. &
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item bureau
\item maison
\item n'importe où tant que vous avez un ordinateur
\end{tabenumerate}\\
\addlinespace
Chemin à poursuivre pour arriver à cette carrière:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quelle sorte de diplôme faut-il obtenir: université, collège, ou autre?
\item Faut-il aller dans une école privée ou spécialisée en formation professionnelle?
\end{tabitemize}
&
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Aller à une université n'est pas requis.
\item Un diplôme en informatique vous aidera à être embauché.
\item Les employeurs recherchent les gens qui ont un bon montant d'expérience.
\item La plupart des gens ont leurs projets logiciels sur un site Web appelé \href{https://github.com/}{GitHub}. Cela peut être utilisé pour prouver votre expérience.
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Programme à poursuivre:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quel est le nom du programme dont il faut poursuivre?
\item Quel est le nom du diplôme à obtenir?
\end{tabitemize} &
L'informatique\\
\addlinespace
Institutions possibles:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Nomme trois institutions académiques qui offrent ce programme
\item Combien d'années durent ce programme?
\item Faut-il continuer ces études après que le programme soit terminé?
\end{tabitemize} &
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item Université de Waterloo – 5 années
\item Université de Toronto – 4 années
\item Université de York – 4 années
\end{tabenumerate}\\
\addlinespace
Préalables:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quelles cours de l'école secondaire sont nécessaires pour entrer dans ce programme?
\item Quelle moyen (average) a t-on besoin d'avoir pour entrer dans le programme?
\item A t-on besoin d'un portfolio ou d'un entretien?
\item Y-a-t-il d'autres exigences ou préalables requises?
\end{tabitemize} &
\begin{tabitemize}
\item cours: fonctions avancées, calcul et vecteurs, n'importe quel niveau d'anglais 12U, un autre cours 4U
\item plus que 90 %
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Frais scolaires:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Combien coûtent les frais pour entrer dans le programme?
\item Combien coûtent les frais de résidence?
\item Combien coûte un plan de nourriture? (meal plan)
\end{tabitemize} &
\begin{tabitemize}
\item programme: 15 000 \$
\item résidence: 4 000 \$
\item plan de nourriture: 2 000 \$
\item total: 21 000 \$
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Autres faits intéressants &
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Tout comme les langages classiques, il existe de nombreux langages de programmation.
\item Ce n'est pas très difficile à coder, il suffit de le pratiquer souvent.
\item Écrire du code est comme écrire un document ou un livre, c'est juste un langage différent.
\end{tabitemize}\\
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
```

It takes up two pages, page 1:

[image]

page 2:

[image]

I want the header row to be repeated on the second page automatically.
I do not want to manually add it again.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer since it seems to solve your problem, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this. See `xltabular` package [document](https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/xltabular/xltabular-doc.pdf) page.8. You don't need `longtable` package if you use `xltabular` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, xltabular, enumitem, hyperref}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{
label=\textbullet, nosep, leftmargin=*,
before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
after ={\end{minipage}}}

\newlist{tabenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenumerate]{label*=\arabic*.,
                       leftmargin=*,
               nosep,
               before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
               after=\end{minipage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{p{0.5\linewidth} X}
\label{tab:choix-de-carriere-different}\\
\caption{Choix de carrière: ingénieur logiciel}\\
\toprule
Information & Recherche \\
\midrule\endfirsthead
\toprule
Information & Recherche \\
\midrule\endhead
Description de la carrière &
Les ingénieurs logiciels se concentrent sur l'application des principes d'ingénierie aux programmes. Chaque ingénieur logiciel écrit et valide le code des programmes d'une entreprise. Tout comme les avocats, les ingénieurs en logiciel se spécialisent dans différents domaines. Il y a le développement Web, le traitement de texte, le développement de jeux.\\
\addlinespace
Habiletés et compétences nécessaires pour cet emploi &
\begin{tabitemize} 
\item savoir le codage 
\item bien à créer la documentation 
\item savoir des langages de programmation 
\item savoir des compilateurs 
\item savoir des licences de logiciels 
\item bien au débogage  
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Le salaire annuel & 83 345 \$\\ 
\addlinespace
Nomme trois différents endroits pour travailler en faisant cette carrière. Par exemple, une infirmière peut travailler dans un hôpital, une clinique privée ou dans des maisons de retraites. &
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item bureau
\item maison
\item n'importe où tant que vous avez un ordinateur
\end{tabenumerate}\\
\addlinespace
Chemin à poursuivre pour arriver à cette carrière:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quelle sorte de diplôme faut-il obtenir: université, collège, ou autre?
\item Faut-il aller dans une école privée ou spécialisée en formation professionnelle?
\end{tabitemize}
&
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Aller à une université n'est pas requis.
\item Un diplôme en informatique vous aidera à être embauché.
\item Les employeurs recherchent les gens qui ont un bon montant d'expérience.
\item La plupart des gens ont leurs projets logiciels sur un site Web appelé \href{https://github.com/}{GitHub}. Cela peut être utilisé pour prouver votre expérience.
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Programme à poursuivre:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quel est le nom du programme dont il faut poursuivre?
\item Quel est le nom du diplôme à obtenir?
\end{tabitemize} &
L'informatique\\
\addlinespace
Institutions possibles:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Nomme trois institutions académiques qui offrent ce programme
\item Combien d'années durent ce programme?
\item Faut-il continuer ces études après que le programme soit terminé?
\end{tabitemize} &
\begin{tabenumerate}
\item Université de Waterloo – 5 années
\item Université de Toronto – 4 années
\item Université de York – 4 années
\end{tabenumerate}\\
\addlinespace
Préalables:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Quelles cours de l'école secondaire sont nécessaires pour entrer dans ce programme?
\item Quelle moyen (average) a t-on besoin d'avoir pour entrer dans le programme?
\item A t-on besoin d'un portfolio ou d'un entretien?
\item Y-a-t-il d'autres exigences ou préalables requises?
\end{tabitemize} &
\begin{tabitemize}
\item cours: fonctions avancées, calcul et vecteurs, n'importe quel niveau d'anglais 12U, un autre cours 4U
\item plus que 90 %
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Frais scolaires:

\begin{tabitemize}
\item Combien coûtent les frais pour entrer dans le programme?
\item Combien coûtent les frais de résidence?
\item Combien coûte un plan de nourriture? (meal plan)
\end{tabitemize} &
\begin{tabitemize}
\item programme: 15 000 \$
\item résidence: 4 000 \$
\item plan de nourriture: 2 000 \$
\item total: 21 000 \$
\end{tabitemize}\\
\addlinespace
Autres faits intéressants &
\begin{tabitemize}
\item Tout comme les langages classiques, il existe de nombreux langages de programmation.
\item Ce n'est pas très difficile à coder, il suffit de le pratiquer souvent.
\item Écrire du code est comme écrire un document ou un livre, c'est juste un langage différent.
\end{tabitemize}\\
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is an easy solution that worked for me.

Comment: @Amarakon You are welcome! This will add header for all the continued pages, if you have even longer table.